# Android save media to gallery MediaStoreApi

Tags: android, gallery, media, mediastore

I am using this code to save file to gallery by using MediaStoreApi. It works well on Android api level 29 and higher, but it fails on android api level 28 and lower. Any solution by using MediaStoreApi on lower versions? Thanks in advance!

```
val values = ContentValues().apply {
    val folderName = if (isVideo) {
        Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    } else {
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
    }
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, MimeUtils.guessMimeTypeFromExtension(getExtension(fileName)))
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, folderName + "/${context.getString(R.string.app_name)}/")
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
}

val collection = if (isVideo) {
    MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
} else {
    MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
}
val fileUri = context.contentResolver.insert(collection, values) ?: return

if (isVideo) {
    context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w").use { descriptor ->
        descriptor?.let {
            FileOutputStream(descriptor.fileDescriptor).use { out ->
                val videoFile = File(filePath)
                FileInputStream(videoFile).use { inputStream ->
                    val buf = ByteArray(8192)
                    while (true) {
                        val sz = inputStream.read(buf)
                        if (sz <= 0) break
                        out.write(buf, 0, sz)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(fileUri).use { out ->
        val bmOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
        val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, bmOptions)
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out)
        bmp.recycle()
    }
}
values.clear()
values.put(if (isVideo) MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING else MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
context.contentResolver.update(fileUri, values, null, null)
```

Comment: Below 29 you cannot use the .RELATIVE.PATH column. You will get warnings/exceptions for that then. Use the .DATA column instead and supply a full path. And do not use IS_PENDING.

Comment: I checked for these fields, but, anyway it gives me ```java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/external_primary/images/media``` error.

Comment: `MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY` is also added on api level 29.

Comment: Then choose a different one. Android Studio IDE wil tell you several if you type MediaStore. and wait for the window that comes up. Try MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL.

Comment: Oh... you cannot use .getContentUri() either.